# Python: Unexpected behaviour when overriding properties

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, properties, getter-setter

I would like to inherit from a class containing a property `x`, and then make this property read-only in the child class by overriding the setter. This does not work if `__init__` in the parent class uses the original setter. Consider the following code.

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, x=1):
        # I want the following line to use the setter defined in the Parent
        # class, even when __init__ is called from Child using super.
        self.x = x
        # Other initialization of Parent goes here.

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        """Check that x is non-negative."""
        if value < 0:
            raise ValueError("x must be non-negative.")
        self._x = value


class Child(Parent):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()  # Need this for initialization.

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self._y

    @y.setter
    def y(self, value):
        """x can only be written to implicitly by setting y."""
        self._y = value
        self._x = abs(value)

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        raise AttributeError("Illegal access to x")
```

If I now try to instantiate `Child`, I get `AttributeError: Illegal access to x` because when the line `self.x = x` is called, the `x` setter of `Child` is called instead of the `x` setter of `Parent`. How can I get it to use the setter of `Parent` in a Pythonic way?

To be clear, when `self.x = ...` appears in a method of `Parent`, it should always make use of the `x` setter in `Parent`, and when `self.x = ...` appears in a method of `Child`, it should always make use of the `x` setter in `Child`, and thus raise an exception.

Comment: You cannot inherit properties like this, you can do: `Child.x = Parent.x.setter(Parent.x.fset)` after class initialization.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary That doesn't work. It does not make `x` read-only for `Child`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem myself by swapping out

```python
self.x = x
```

in `Parent.__init__` with

```python
Parent.x.fset(self, x)
```

I can also get rid of

```python
@property
def x(self):
    return self._x
```

in `Child` if instead of `@x.setter`, I use `@Parent.x.setter`.

Comment: @NizamMohamed Yes, it would, since trying to write to the child `x` would raise an `AttributeError`.